# CPU intensive application with Compiler optimization flag turned on/off

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library, compiler-optimization

I wrote a small program to compare the performance of my laptops. To make the program CPU intensive, I implemented Rabin-Karp pattern matching algorithm with some multi-threading code (implemented via Parallel API).

I noticed that when the program is executed with compiler optimization flag turned off then it takes significantly more time than what it takes to execute with optimization flag turned on.

For example:

- Time taken (when optimization flag turned off): 40 seconds (approx.)
- Time taken (when optimization flag turned on): 18 seconds (approx.)

I am curious to know as what sort of optimization is being applied by the compiler that adds to such significant improvement in performance. Any pointer's on how to understand as whats going on when the code is executed with this flag turned on/off will be really helpful.

**Code**

```
void Main()
{
    Dictionary<string,bool> collection = new Dictionary<string,bool>();
    IEnumerable<string> commonWords = File.ReadAllLines(@"G:\LINQPad4\words.txt")
        .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).Select(t => t.Trim());

    string magna_carta = File.ReadAllText(@"G:\LINQPad4\magna-carta.txt");

    Parallel.ForEach(commonWords,
    () => new Dictionary<string,bool>(),
    (word, loopState, localState) =>
    {
        RabinKarpAlgo rbAlgo = new RabinKarpAlgo(magna_carta,word);
        localState.Add(word,rbAlgo.Match());
        return localState;
    },
    (localState) =>
    {
        lock(collection){
            foreach(var item in localState)
            {
                collection.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
            }
        }
    });

    collection.Dump();
}

public class RabinKarpAlgo
{
    private readonly string inputString;
    private readonly string pattern;
    private ulong siga = 0;
    private ulong sigb = 0;
    private readonly ulong Q = 100007;
    private readonly ulong D = 256;

    public RabinKarpAlgo(string inputString, string pattern)
    {
        this.inputString = inputString;
        this.pattern = pattern;
    }

    public bool Match()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < pattern.Length; i++)
        {
            siga = (siga * D + (ulong)inputString[i]) % Q;
            sigb = (sigb * D + (ulong)pattern[i]) % Q;
        }

        if(siga == sigb)
            return true;

        ulong pow = 1;
        for (int k = 1; k <= pattern.Length - 1; k++)
            pow = (pow * D) % Q;

        for (int j = 1; j <= inputString.Length - pattern.Length; j++)
        {
            siga = (siga + Q - pow * (ulong)inputString[j - 1] %Q) % Q;
            siga = (siga * D + (ulong)inputString[j + pattern.Length - 1]) % Q;

            if (siga == sigb)
            {
                if (inputString.Substring(j, pattern.Length) == pattern)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

**You can download the related files from the following gitHub repository** : [Rabin-Karp Test](https://github.com/pawanmishra/Rabin_Karp_Pattern_Search)

**Article** : [Performance Testing](http://weblogs.asp.net/pawanmishra/archive/2012/06/10/inauguration-of-my-laptop.aspx)

Comment: As a guess, 2 ways to see the difference would be 1) compare the IL generated for those 2 cases and then 2) ngen both cases and compare the generated assembly.  With debug on, the JIT skips lots of optimizations, for instance.  Without looking at the generated output, I would think you'd be left just guessing?

Comment: The IL code looks almost similar in both the cases except few differences like "nop" & other statements are missing in the optimized code. I will try the "ngen" approach and compare the generated assemblies.

Comment: @JamesManning I think you don't need ngen, you can compile the code, start it and then attach debugger and look at the assembly code.

Answer (score 3):

in your special case there are 3 for loops, which are inside a parallel foreach,
i strongly believe that most optimizations are done there through dynamic loop transformations and of course, the math part.

here are some examples what can be done with a loop: [Loop transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_transformation)

Eric Lippert from the C# compiler team has a blog entry on this:
[what does the optimize switch do](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/11/what-does-the-optimize-switch-do.aspx)